# What happens if I loose the nonce?

Tags: baking, nonce

I baked a block such as `blockNumber % 32 == 0` so I am required to reveal my nonce at the next cycle. If I irretrievably loose this nonce due to hardware failure or misconfiguration, can I still bake with the same address, or does it become tainted forever ?

Answer (score 3):

No you will only lose the rewards and the fees for this block

Answer (score 0):

The answer can also be found in the documentation: https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/proof_of_stake.html#random-seed.